# How to collect all records at spark executor and process it as batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, drools

In my spark kinesis streaming application I am using foreachBatch to get the streaming data and need to send it to the drools rule engine for further processing.

My requirement is, I need to accumulate all json data in a list/ruleSession and send it for rule engine for processing as a batch at the executor side.

```
//Scala Code Example:
    val dataFrame = sparkSession.readStream
          .format("kinesis")
          .option("streamName", streamName)
          .option("region", region)
          .option("endpointUrl",endpointUrl)
          .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
          .load()


    val query = dataFrame
        .selectExpr("CAST(data as STRING) as krecord")
        .writeStream
        .foreachBatch(function)
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()


     val function = (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
       val ruleSession = kBase.newKieSession() //Drools Rule Session, this is getting created at driver side

         batchDF.foreach(row => { // This piece of code is being run in executor.
               val jsonData: JSONData = jsonHandler.convertStringToJSONType(row.mkString)
               ruleSession.insert(jsonData) // Getting a null pointer exception here as the ruleSession is not available in executor.
             }
           )

       ruleHandler.processRule(ruleSession) // Again this is in the driver scope.
      }
```

In the above code, the problem I am facing is: the function used in foreachBatch is getting executed at driver side and the code inside batchDF.foreach is getting executed at worker/executor side, and thus failing to get he ruleSession.

Is there any way to run the whole function at each executor side?

OR

Is there a better way to accumulate all the data in a batch DataFrame after transformation and send it to next process from within the executor/worker?

Comment: I would think that rather than running `foreach`, you could use `foreachPartition`  (or mapPartition if you want return info) where you would open a connection to the drools system. From that point, you would iterate over the dataset within each partition sending each to the drools system (or you might send that whole chunk to drools). In the foreachPartition section, you could then close the connect (if applicable).

Comment: @codeaperature,  That's a nice thought, let me give it a try, I will let you know how things goes. Meanwhile do you know if the open and close of a ForeachWriter is invoked for every batch or is it just once for an executor? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @codeaperature, I did it bit differently, instead of the forEachBatch I used the forEach and in the ForEachWriter open method I initialized the drools session and in process method did all the insertion/batching of rules to session, and in close method final execution of rules using the same session.I choose forEach over forEachBatch as doing another round of iteration in forEatchBatch did not made much sense.  I did this getting inspired from your comment, if you could provide the same as an answer I will accept it and share the code sample I did in its comment, Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work ... Rather than running foreach, you could use foreachBatch or foreachPartition (or or a map version like mapPartition if you want return info). In this portion, open a connection to the drools system. From that point, iterate over the dataset within each partition (or batch) sending each to the drools system (or you might send that whole chunk to drools). In the foreachPartition / foreachBatch section, at the end, close the connect (if applicable).

Comment: Posting a sample code inspired from your suggestion below as there is a word limit to post in comment. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

@codeaperature, This is how I achieved batching, inspired from your answer, posting it as an answer as this exceeds the word limit in a comment.

- Using foreach on dataframe and passing in a ForeachWriter.
- Initializing the rule session in open method of ForeachWriter.
- Adding each input JSON to rule session in process method.
- Execute the rule in close method with the rule session loaded with batch of data.

//Scala code:

```
val dataFrame = sparkSession.readStream
          .format("kinesis")
          .option("streamName", streamName)
          .option("region", region)
          .option("endpointUrl",endpointUrl)
          .option("initialPosition", "TRIM_HORIZON")
          .load()

val query = dataFrame
  .selectExpr("CAST(data as STRING) as krecord")
  .writeStream
  .foreach(dataConsumer)
  .start()

val dataConsumer = new ForeachWriter[Row] {

  var ruleSession: KieSession = null;

  def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = { // first open is called once for every batch
    ruleSession = kBase.newKieSession()
    true
  }

  def process(row: Row) = { // the process method will be called for a batch of records
    val jsonData: JSONData = jsonHandler.convertStringToJSONType(row.mkString)
    ruleSession.insert(jsonData) // Add all input json to rule session.
  }

  def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = { // after calling process for all records in bathc close is called
    val factCount = ruleSession.getFactCount
    if (factCount > 0) {
      ruleHandler.processRule(ruleSession) //batch processing of rule
    }
  }
}
```